# запустить библиотеку Isaac gym на Windows

Tags: python, windows, nvidia

Вопрос собственно простой. Можно ли запустить библиотеку Isaac gym на Windows?

[ссылка на Github.](https://github.com/NVIDIA-Omniverse/IsaacGymEnvs)

Библиотека качается. Организуется виртуалка с питоном нужной версии. Всё необходимое закидывается в виртуальную среду. При запуске ошибка.

```
    raise RuntimeError("No gym module found for the active version of Python (%d.%d)" % (major, minor))
RuntimeError: No gym module found for the active version of Python (3.6)
```

.
.
.

Если кому то интересно, то ниже мои попытки понять почему появляется ошибка:

Залез в файл gymapi.py, он указан как крайний в выводе ошибки. Там есть код, который сравнивает версию питона и выбирает соответствующие bindings.

```
if major == 3 and minor == 6:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(lib_dir, platform, "py36"))
```

Проблема в том что по данному пути нет папки для Windows, только для Linux.

Пытался поставить ubuntu и запустить на нём. Запустилось, но вылетает. Вылетает я так понимаю потому что для обучения и вывода изображения используется процессор, а библиотека рассчитана, что логично, на видеокарту.

Много возился я с установкой и подключением видеокарты с CUDA. Но так ничего и не вышло.